# Unable to compare two instances of opaque types

Tags: swift, opaque-types

It's interesting to see that we can now declare return values that are protocols with associated types.

The following throws an error and I don't understand the error.

```
protocol Plant: Equatable {
    var maintenance: String { get }
}

struct Rose: Plant {
    let height: Float // inches
    let maintenance = "Water once a day."
}

struct Orchid: Plant {
    let height: Float // inches
    let maintenance = "Water once a month."
}

func makePlant1() -> some Plant {
    Rose(height: 4)
}

func makePlant2() -> some Plant {
    Orchid(height: 8)
}

let plant1: some Plant = makePlant1()
let plant2: some Plant = makePlant2()

func asdf() {
    let condition: Bool = (plant1 == plant2) // error: ambiguous without more context
    print(condition)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a function to return `some Plant` then the compiler will look at the content of the function to see what real type is returned and in your example you are returning different types, `Rose` and `Orchid`.

This breaks the requirement from `Equatable` that `Self` must be the same,  that you use `some` doesn't mean that this requirement disappears.

The error message you get is a bit confusing but if you change it to

```
print(plant1 == plant2)
```

the error is more informative

> Cannot convert value of type 'some Plant' (result of 'makePlant2()') to expected argument type 'some Plant' (result of 'makePlant1')

To be able to use `==` here you need to use objects created by the same function

```
func makePlant1(_ value: Float) -> some Plant {
    Rose(height: value)
}

let plant1 = makePlant1(4)
let plant2 = makePlant1(4)
let plant3 = makePlant1(6)

print(plant1 == plant2) // true
print(plant1 == plant3) // false
```

[Here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/187/how-to-use-opaque-return-types-in-swift-5-1) is an informative article on the topic from hackingwithswift.com

Answer (score 1):

The protocol `Plant` conforms to `Equatable`. This means that the types that conform to `Plant` also conform to `Equatable`.

`Rose` conforms to `Plant`, so it's also `Equatable`: you can differentiate two **Rose**s.

Same for `Orchid`: you can differentiate two **Orchid**s.

But you can't equate a `Rose` to an `Orchid`: they both conform to the same protocol, but they don't inherit from the same class.

If you try to equate two of the same type, it works - see examples below.

**1) Equating instances that follow the same protocol**

```
protocol Plant: Equatable {
    var maintenance: String { get }
}

struct Rose: Plant {
    let height: Float // inches
    let maintenance = "Water once a day."
}

struct Orchid: Plant {
    let height: Float // inches
    let maintenance = "Water once a month."
}

    func makePlant2() -> some Plant {
        Orchid(height: 8)
    }

    func makePlant3() -> some Plant {
        Orchid(height: 10)
    }

    func compare() {
        let plant2: Orchid = makePlant2() as! Orchid
        let plant3: Orchid = makePlant3() as! Orchid

        let conditionPlant: Bool = (plant3 == plant2) // both are Equatable of the same type
        print(conditionPlant)
    }
```

**2) Equating classes that inherit from the same type**

```
protocol Plant: Equatable {
    var maintenance: String { get }
}

class Tree: Plant {
    static func == (lhs: Tree, rhs: Tree) -> Bool {
        lhs.name == rhs.name
    }
    
    let name: String
    var maintenance = "Never"
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Oak: Tree { }
class Sequoia: Tree { }

    func makeTree1() -> Tree {
        Oak(name: "Shady oasis")
    }
    
    func makeTree2() -> Tree {
        Sequoia(name: "Old woody")
    }

    func compare() {
        let tree1 = makeTree1()
        let tree2 = makeTree2()

        let conditionTree: Bool = (tree1 == tree2) // both are Equatable, inherit from the same type
        print(conditionTree)
    }
```